# XAttribute.SetValue converts &quot;

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xattribute

In my application I'm using `XAttribute.SetValue(...)` to set the value of an xml-attribute. The value is provided by the user.

I have the following methode to set the attribute-value:

```
private void SetValue(XAttribute attribute, string input)
{
    attribute.SetValue(input);
}
```

If the input is `Hello "World"` then the value of the attribute is: `Hello &quot;World&quot;`

This is what I've expected.

If the input is already "masked" like `Hello &quot;World&quot;` then the value of the attribute is: `Hello &amp;quot;World&amp;quot;`

That's not correct.

Is there a way to avoid this conversion?

Comment: You should of removed the double quotes from input before call the method.  You can remove the double quotes simply by using replace : input = input.Replace("\"", "");

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it, but you can make sure the input is not already encoded with something like `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input)` before you call `SetValue`

Comment: Thanks. `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input)` solved the problem. Post it as answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not stop `SetValue` encoding characters such as `&` to entity codes. So, to avoid them being double encoded, you can make sure your input is not encoded to start with. You can do this using:

`System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDocode(input)`

Or, if you have a reference to `System.Web` already,

`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input)`